How to properly configure SPF/DKIM and stripe link to prevent being filtered out by Outlook
As part of our system, we send out an email using a dedicated IP on sendgrid on behalf of our customers that involves paying an invoice for the customer. The email often includes a generated Stripe link.
Our SPF and DKIM checks are all coming out as passes, and 100% of the emails going to gmail or outlook accounts we're testing with (including our personal emails) are going through successfully. However, a small subset of users we email (all outlook so far) never receive the emails - no even to their junk/spam folder.
One of them let us look through their outlook logs and found that Microsoft was automatically filtering out the emails as potential phishing attempts.
We add the stripe link in 2 ways:

we add the stripe link to the email body itself as a raw URL
we embed a payment button in the invoice PDF that we attach to the email. the button we use is formatted as following:

<a className="no-underline" href={data.remittanceInstructions.paymentLink}>
  <button className="bg-blue-900 text-white px-3 py-1 rounded border border-blue-100">
    Pay Now
  </button>
</a>

Does anyone have any ideas of what may be causing this? My current thought is that outlook may be concerned about the button being styled as it is - I'm wondering if anyone else has programmatically sent stripe links to 3rd party users successfully or if anyone knows of any issues with the code above.
